# Android Sqlite: Exibindo conteúdo do banco em textView?

Tags: android, sqlite, select

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para exibir conteúdo do banco de dados Sqlite em textviews. Eu estou usando o seguindo método para exibir em uma CustomListView:

```
    public Cursor getAllData ()
{
    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.DiferencaPercentual.TABELA; //pega todos os dados da tabela
    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}
```

E depois eu repasso isso para um adapter dizendo quais são os campos do meu custom list view que é cada coisa:

```
    @Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
{
    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView textViewPersonPIN = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    textViewPersonPIN.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));
}
```

E depois eu passo isso tudo para a activity, no método onCreate:

```
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(ListarCliente.this, clienteDAO.findById(51));
            customAdapter = new ClienteAdapter(ListarCliente.this, clienteDAO.getAllData());
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
```

E, num método a parte:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        clienteDAO.insertData(data.getExtras().getString("tag_nome"),
                              data.getExtras().getString("tag_email"));

        customAdapter.changeCursor(clienteDAO.getAllData());
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é, não tem uma forma mais simples d'eu pegar o conteúdo do banco de dados e rapidamente exibir numa textView, só para o usuário poder editar as informações?

Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou lhe dar um exemplo que tenho certeza que funciona. Como você não mostrou seu código completo, vou apresentar uma forma, você deve adapta-lo e estuda-lo:

1 - Você precisa tornar cada campo da sua `listView` clicável, para que possa ser passado via `putExtra();` as informações de cada item individualmente- EXEMPLO:

```
...
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

...
...

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) {
                TextView idTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
                TextView descTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

                String id = idTextView.getText().toString();
                String titulo = titleTextView.getText().toString();
                String desc = descTextView.getText().toString();

                Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ModifyTodoActivity.class);
                modify_intent.putExtra("titulo", titulo);
                modify_intent.putExtra("desc", desc);
                modify_intent.putExtra("id", id);

                startActivity(modify_intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

2 - Para exibir numa `TextView` crie uma nova atividade e faça essa lógica:

**ExibindoActivity.class**:

```
...
...

//título do texto.   
        titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subject_edittext);

//descrição do texto. 
        descText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_edittext);


//RECEBE OS VALORES DA ATIVIDADE PRINCIPAL

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("titulo");
        String desc = intent.getStringExtra("desc");

    //EXIBINDO NO TEXTVIEW, CONFORME VOCÊ PEDIU - NOME E DESCRIÇÃO SÃO EXEMPLOS

            titleText.setText(name);
            descText.setText(desc);

...
}
```

Caso queira editar os campos, segue abaixo a lógica:

2 - Você precisará criar uma atividade que irá servir somente para modificar os campos, é um dica, pois assim o cliente será direcionado para uma tela de edição. NÃO PRECISARÁ DE SELECT, tudo será passado por parâmetros:

**ModificandoActivity.class**:

```
public class ModificandoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

...
...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

...
//Abra o banco
//NÃO SE PREOCUPE COM SELECT, OS TEXTOS VIRÃO POR getStringExtra();
//Abrir o banco é somente para dar o update e delete, CASO VOCÊ ASSIM QUEIRA

//título do texto. Aqui abrimos um EditText para que ele possa ser editado     
        titleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject_edittext);

//descrição do texto. Aqui abrimos um EditText para que ele possa ser editado
        descText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description_edittext);

//Botão update. Aqui abrimos um Button para para salvar as mudanças

        updateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_update);

//Botão delete. Aqui abrimos um Button para para deletar a o texto NO BANCO
        deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

//RECEBE OS VALORES DA ATIVIDADE PRINCIPAL

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("titulo");
        String desc = intent.getStringExtra("desc");

        _id = Long.parseLong(id);

//EXIBINDO NO EDITTEXT - NOME E DESCRIÇÃO SÃO EXEMPLOS

        titleText.setText(name);
        descText.setText(desc);

        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

//ESSA PARTE É FUNDAMENTAL, POIS O CLIENTE PODERÁ DELETAR OU DAR UPDATE
//DEPOIS QUE ELE ESCOLHER, O CASE IRÁ SETAR O NOVO VALOR OU DELETAR

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_update:

//SETANDO O NOVO TEXTO NA STRING
            String titulo = titleText.getText().toString();
            String desc = descText.getText().toString();

//UPDATE NO BANCO É UM EXEMPLO

            dbManager.update(_id, titulo, desc);
            this.returnHome();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_delete:
//ele pega o ID, busca no banco e deleta a coluna referente (é somente uma lógica)
            dbManager.delete(_id);
            this.returnHome();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Essa é uma ideia genial, cara! Só uma última pergunta para eu te marcar como melhor resposta: O botão de editar está num ContextMenu, o método onItemClick seria ativado ainda? UPDATE: eu encontrei uma forma de fazer isso. Obrigado amigo!

Comment: Veja isto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419357/how-to-open-menu-context-android-with-click-button-in-listview-adapter

Comment: Conseguiu, Diego?

Comment: Por enquanto não, mas acredito que estou no caminho certo! Talvez eu devesse criar um método com o conteúdo do onItemCLick e repassar para o onLongItemClick, mas vou procurar uma alternativa mais simples

Comment: Ok, encontrei um link que está me ajudando ( http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/ ). Se eu conseguir te avisarei! obrigado!

Comment: Ta certo. Avisa! E esse link que te dei? Não serve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419357/how-to-open-menu-context-android-with-click-button-in-listview-adapter

Comment: Cara, consegui pegar informações com LongClick e Click normal, e ainda usar o contextMenu. Muito obrigado mano! Depois vou postar a resposta de como fazer isso numa pergunta a parte, pq deu um trampo gigante de achar XD vlw mano!

Comment: Demorou, cara. Te enviei um e-mail e vou postar a resposta aqui no stack da solução que encontrei daqui a pouco